# HTML code is not rendering in an email sent by the Gmail app

Tags: html, gmail, href, zapier, render-html

I've been using the below html code and had not experienced any problems until this past month. My HTML code is not rendering in an email sent by the Gmail app on the Zapier platform. Sometimes the hyperlink works and other times it does not. Is there something wrong with the html formcade hyperlink?

I appreciate any help or any context as to why it's not working

<a href="https://formfacade.com/"target="_blank"
style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;">Begin Survey

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The anchor (`<a>`) tag is not closed. Although this is not always an issue, it could cause unexpected errors like you are apparently having.

Also, remember to add spacing between attributes to avoid confusion (there is no spacing between the link and `target="_blank"`).

Comment: @Linquia Customer does closing the tag and adding spaces like Jahtomini make any difference?

`<a href="https://formfacade.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;">Begin Survey</a>`. ...sometimes browsers can infer a closed tag but it depends on what they choose to do and may be a simple reason why it's not working.